# Threads in Java vs Async Tasks in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await

I am trying programming in `android` using `Xamarin.android` using C#. While watching a tutorial of android I have found out that they are using `Thread` for asynchronous programming but in C# Async/Await is what i like to do.

So my question is - Can these `Threads` be replaced directly by `Async/Await Tasks` in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what sort of asynchronous programming you're talking about. If it's background processing, then you'll still want a task on a different thread. You can still use async/await for that, of course.

If it's really just asynchronous IO - make a web request, wait for the result, etc - then yes, async/await should make this much simpler, and you should be able to avoid having any extra threads.